# how can i do link detection instead of discord command

Tags: python, discord

```
@bot.command()
async def steam(ctx, *, steam):
    response = requests.get(
        f"https://converter.api.dedns.org/" f"{steam}")
```

The code detects this "steam" command.
when I type in "steam profileurl" command, it gives me its steamid as an answer.
i want steamid to respond when I send a direct profileurl instead of the "steam" command
so it detects steam as a command, so I want it to detect a url instead. Without writing steam to the command

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_message does this help? you can create a message listener, check if it matches the url (say with regex or just string compare), and do your requests thing afterwards.

Comment: can you throw a sample code

Comment: fixed it, thanks for ur help